# Unity 3d Player climbing walls

Tags: unity-game-engine

I found that if I start to walk in the corner, my player starts to slowly going up (like climbing or floating). I wonder did smn fixed that?

Comment: Don't worry. This is common. Your player gets stuck and slowly climbs up. You could prevent that by placing an invisible box with 45° of rotation with respect to a wall. This will stop player from entering that corner. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

You might have made the object move by the y axis.